# How can I download entire dropbox folder using Dropbox API?

Tags: google-app-engine, download, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox REST API to perform different operations on users' Dropbox Acount (using Google App Engine). But folder download using [files (GET)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#files-GET) is giving 404 error: File Not Found. Whereas the same method is working if I try to download a single file, say a .txt or .docx file.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `?dl=1` to the end of a Dropbox folder share URL and you'll trigger downloading a .zip of the folder in question. So, `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/123456789` for regular folder access becomes `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/123456789?dl=1` to downlaod the zip.

Comment: Yes, this works. One drawback though. If the folder is not with static name for example someone can rename the folder name, there is no way to know the encrypted url to be able download the .zip @Shawn Taylor

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `/metadata` to get a list of files, then download each one with a separate call. `/files` says that it "Downloads a file". A folder is not a file.

Comment: Any other workaround to download entire folder as a .zip file directly?

Comment: You could possibly generate the share link, then download a zip from that link. It's described for a similar situation here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227324/programmatically-download-content-from-shared-dropbox-folder-links/20243081#20243081