# How to know the dropbox folder's shard link if the name is changed

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, webclient

I'm using dropbox Core API and faced one issue related to folder downloading. 
For example I'm just calling folders *shared link* that I want to download- `"https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sssadadsd/afgasga?dl=1"` 
and it's automatically
compresses it into `.zip` archive and downloads it to my pc.

***The question:*** 
What if the user renames the folder, 
how can I know the *shared link* without going manually to the Dropbox and copying the *shared link*? Is that even possible? 
Maybe can encrypt somehow using the `access_token` and `folder name`? Have no idea, just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox shared links don't currently persist across file/folder moves/renames. So, if file or folder is moved or renamed, you'll need to call [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares) again to get a new shared link.

You may want to use [/delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#delta) to watch for changes that would indicate moves/renames.

Comment: How did I miss this in the documentation... Just what I've been looking for. Json results `url` key holding that share link. Simple and easy, thanks. @Greg