# Download APK from Dropbox without the Dropbox API on Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, apk, dropbox

I want to download an APK from dropbox without using the API. I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // Initialise the button
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new DownloadFilesTask().execute();

            // Show Download confirmation
            Toast confirmDownload = Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"Download is complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            confirmDownload.show();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Asynchronous Task Class
 * Will invoke a new stream with which the apk is to be downloaded
 */
private static class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    /**
     * Concurrent process to download the file from the path provided
     * @param voids Parameters of the method are not used
     * @return Return value of the method is unimportant
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            URL download = new URL(pathToAPK);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc= Channels.newChannel(download.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(dowloadPath+ "file.apk");
            fileOut.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0,1 << 24 );
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
            rbc.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        return null;
    }
```

The file downloads successfully however when I try to open the file I get a:

Parse error: There was a problem while parsing the package

My guess is the file is corrupted for some reason. Any guesses?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically Download Content from Shared Dropbox Folder Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227324/programmatically-download-content-from-shared-dropbox-folder-links)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, changing the dl to 1, does not solve the issue. Please see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone out there getting this annoying error.

Step 1: Change the dl at the end of the dropbox URL to 1

Step 2: Use the [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) to download the file

Works like a charm! No need for streams etc..

```
    private void download() {
        DownloadManager downloadManager =  (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(dropboxPath);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

        request.setDescription("new version");
        request.setTitle("Updated App");
        request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(pathApk,"new-app.apk");
//        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(pathApk + "test.txt"));
//        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(pathApk + "test.txt"));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        // Download will immediately
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }
```